# Is there a way to group part of a column?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a TAB file laid out like this:

```
1   56  .   T   C   1963    .   HaplotypeScore=3.6230;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;QD=33.84;MLEAC=1;SOR=1.077
1   226 .   A   G   1600    .   HaplotypeScore=3.0421;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=59.02;MQ0=0;QD=32.00;SOR=0.954
1   670 .   A   G   2878    .   HaplotypeScore=9.0166;QD=34.24;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;SOR=0.864
1   817 .   C   T   1425    .   HaplotypeScore=0.9958;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQ0=0;QD=26.89;SOR=0.850
```

my goal is to create a for loop that pulls the `QD=` value alone from that column and produce a .txt file like this:

```
QD=33
QD=32
QD=34
QD=26
```

So far I have come up with something like this:

awk -F'[: ]' '{print $8}' inputfile

or maybe even using a sed command. But at the moment I am completely lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your other option is `awk` which is the swiss-army knife of text processing. It will be orders of magnitude faster than spawning multiple subshells and piping information to different utilities on large files. If you have less than a 1000 records (lines), you won't notice much difference. If you have millions of lines, the difference is a fraction of a second with `awk` or several minutes using multiple utilities.

`awk` process each record (line) in a file applying the rules you write to each record in the order you write them. There are two special rules, `BEGIN` (run before reading lines begins, useful for assigning variables, printing header rows, etc..) and the `END` rule that is run after all lines are processed, to allow you to process any data collected in arrays or printing footer rows, etc..)

Here you need a single rule that splits the last field into an array based on the `';'` delimiter, e.g.

```
awk -F'\t' '{split($NF,arr,";"); sub(/[.].*$/,"",arr[6]); print arr[6]}' file
```

Above `-F'\t'` tells `awk` to use a tab character as a field separator. (note: you can omit the `-F'\t'` since `awk` split fields by whitespace to begin with), then `split` splits the last (`NF`) field into the array `arr` and then `sub` applies the regular expression `/[.].*$/` to chop everything from the `'.'` to end of field off leaving the whole number shown in your question, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in the file named `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{split($NF,arr,";"); sub(/[.].*$/,"",arr[6]); print arr[6]}' file
QD=33
QD=32
QD=34
QD=26
```

(You can also loop over the elements of `arr` to find the element that begins with `"QD"` if that field many change)

**Position of QD Unknown**

If the position of `"QD"` in the last field is unknown, you can simply loop over the elements of `arr`, e.g. `for (i in arr)` and find the element that begins with `"QD"` and then operate `arr[i]` instead of `arr[6]`, e.g.

```
awk '{
    split($NF,arr,";")
    for (i in arr)
        if (arr[i] ~ /^QD/) {
            sub(/[.].*$/,"",arr[i])
            print arr[i]
            next
        }
}' file
```

You can just change the name from `file` to whatever your filename is and then select-copy and middle-mouse paste the expression into and xterm with the present working directory containing your file, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{
>     split($NF,arr,";")
>     for (i in arr)
>         if (arr[i] ~ /^QD/) {
>             sub(/[.].*$/,"",arr[i])
>             print arr[i]
>             next
>         }
> }' file
QD=33
QD=32
QD=34
QD=26
```

Or if you prefer it as a one-liner, you can do:

```
$ awk '{split($NF,arr,";"); for (i in arr) if (arr[i] ~ /^QD/) { sub(/[.].*$/,"",arr[i]); print arr[i]; next }}' file
QD=33
QD=32
QD=34
QD=26
```

All of the functions used are detailed in the [GNU Awk Users Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions). It is a great reference for learning `awk`. Just click on the table-of-contents and then bookmark a link to the full guide. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi- thankyou so much. The issue I am having is that the position of QD may change in each row. I provided this example to make it easier to understand. Essentially I need to find QD, which I though may be possible using string manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
cut -d';' -f6 file
```

If that is all you need, no need of `sed` or `awk`

To further get only the whole numbers:

```
cut -d';' -f6 file|cut -d. -f1
```

### Edit

Further comments suggest that the order of column where `QD=` is could change, so we can use regex, to find it:

```
grep -Po 'QD=\d+' file
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/fCcDKe/1

Comment: Hi- thankyou so much. The issue I am having is that the position of QD may change in each row. I provided this example to make it easier to understand. Essentially I need to find QD, which I though may be possible using string manipulation.

Comment: That was not clear from the question, I will update my answer

Comment: You may consider reading the [*Useless use of cat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: There are many cases where `cat` can be replaced with `stdin`, however for readability it is fine. UUOC is an old concept, with its benefits, but is just an opinion after all. So, please do not poop where it was clean before :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest should be use `match` function of `awk` since position of `QD` is unknown. Written and tested in link https://ideone.com/EzswQj#stdin

```
awk 'match($NF,/QD=[0-9]+/){print substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using `awk`'s `match` function here, in which we could provide regex what we need to get in output. I have given `QD=[0-9]+` which will match string QD then = then continuous any number of digits after it in the last field. In `march` if a regex is matched then it will set 2 default variables named `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` so I am printing sub-string which prints from RSTART to RLENGTH here.

***Note:*** As per shown samples considering that QD value is coming only once per last column, in case you have multiple values per line then we need to write a while loop in above code.

Comment: Yep, I like the `match()` and `RSTART, RLENGTH` approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, a simple `sed` command would do the task:

```
sed 's/.*;\(QD=[0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
```